# sqlite query performance using nested queries

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

I use the following sqlite query in c#. The query is iterated for 100K items. I feel the execution is slow and by optimizing the query the speed can be increased

```
insert into salesmetrics(salesid, salesrankcount, volumerankcount, countsales,Avgsales) 
select @salesid,sum(salesrank), sum(volumerank), Count(salesrank), avg(salesrank) 
from (select salesrank, volumerank
      from salesindex
      Join SalesData on salesindex.salesindexID = salesData.salesindexID
      where SourceID = @Sourceid
        and Content like @content
      group by salesindex.salesindexID)
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `salesindex` (
    salesindexID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    salesindex TEXT,
    SourceID INTEGER,
    salesrank INTEGER,
    volumerank INTEGER,
    dateAdded DATETIME, 
    UNIQUE(SourceID,dateAdded)
);

CREATE TABLE `SalesData` (
    SalesDataID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    salesindexID INTEGER,
    Content TEXT,
    dateAdded DATETIME,
    UNIQUE(salesindexID,content)
);

CREATE TABLE `salesmetrics` (
   salesmetricsID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   salesID INTEGER,
   SalesRankCount INTEGER,
   VolumeRankCount INTEGER,
   countsales INTEGER,
   SalesRank  FLOAT
);
```

Index on "content" on salesdata table and sourceid on salesindex table

Comment: Show the table definitions, and any indexes you have.

Comment: I have edited to add table structure and index details

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the GROUP BY in the inner query, which is apparently needed to squash multiple matching `SalesData` rows.

Do the `Content` check in a subquery instead:

```
SELECT @salesid,
       SUM(salesrank),
       SUM(volumerank),
       COUNT(salesrank),
       AVG(salesrank)
FROM salesindex
WHERE salesindexID IN (SELECT salesindexID
                       FROM SalesData
                       WHERE Content LIKE @content)
  AND SourceID = @Sourceid;
```

Alternatively, depending on the selectivity of the `Content` lookup, it might be a better idea to do the lookup as a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT @salesid,
       SUM(salesrank),
       SUM(volumerank),
       COUNT(salesrank),
       AVG(salesrank)
FROM salesindex
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM SalesData
              WHERE salesindexID = salesindex.salesindexID
                AND Content LIKE @content)
  AND SourceID = @Sourceid;
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm missing something, I think you could insert directly the select, instead of the select of the select:

```sql
insert into salesmetrics(salesid, salesrankcount, volumerankcount, countsales,Avgsales)
(select @salesid,sum(salesrank), sum(volumerank), Count(salesrank), avg(salesrank)
 from salesindex 
 Join SalesData on salesindex.salesindexID = salesData.salesindexID
 where SourceID = @Sourceid
   and Content like @content
 group by salesindex.salesindexID)
```

Comment: I tried this one earlier. I am getting multiple rows.

Comment: This is not valid SQL.